# How to mount one directory between multiple systems to place logs on one location?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My applications are running on 10 systems and all are generating logs through log4j2..
Want to mount one directory for logs so that application generated logs will directly save on mount directory with server host name .

So that developers and prod support team no need to visit on all servers.. for checking logs.

Mount directory,

Log4j

Comment: Look into [log aggregation](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=log+aggregation&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english) What problems did you face when you just used a shared drive? Check also [ask].

Answer (score -2):

You have to mount one directory for logs so that application generated logs will directly save on mount directory with server host name. Follow these steps:

1. Create a directory on a central server to store the logs. For example, you could create a directory called `/var/log/centralized-logs`.
   On each server that is running your application, mount the central log directory. To do this, you can use the following command:

   `mount -t nfs <central-server-ip>:/var/log/centralized-logs /var/log/centralized-logs`
2. In your application's `log4j2` configuration file, specify the path to the central log directory. For example, if the central log directory is mounted at `/var/log/centralized-logs`, you would add the following line to your log4j2 configuration file:

   `appender.file.File = /var/log/centralized-logs/<server-hostname>.log`
3. The `<server-hostname>` variable will be replaced with the hostname of the server that is running the application. This will ensure that the logs for each server are saved in a separate file in the central log directory.
4. Once you have made the necessary changes, restart your application. Once your application is restarted, the logs will be saved in the central log directory.
5. Now, you can access the logs for all of your servers from a single location. This will make it easier for developers and production support teams to troubleshoot problems.

Here are some additional tips for managing logs:

- Use a centralized logging system to collect logs from all of your servers. This will make it easier to search and analyze logs.
- Configure your log files to rotate on a regular basis. This will prevent your log files from becoming too large and causing performance problems.
- Use a log monitoring tool to track the activity of your servers. This will help you to identify potential problems before they cause outages.

Comment: It isn't a good plan, if access to the central log filesystem fails all your servers could be at risk of failing.

Comment: @DuncG I agree. Better to have n scripts to copy to a central location, where n is the number of OSs you have. n could be two (one for MacOs/other Unixes and one for Windows). If you have a mixed OS infrastructure your least problematic sharing tech could be CIFS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Utkal Keshari Jena!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.